# Unexpected any value in conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast

Tags: typescript, conditional-statements, nestjs, eslint, prisma

The code runs and works fine, but ESLint is screaming at me for an unexpected value in conditional mode. How can I get rid of this problem (I don't want to disable eslint rules)?

This code is responsible for handling the database service and for creating an ADMIN user with the given credentials but first it checks if such an ADMIN already exists in the database.

> error:
> src/lib/data.service.ts   28:11  error  Unexpected any value in
> conditional. An explicit comparison or type cast is required
> @typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions

```
data.service.ts:

@Injectable()
export class DataService extends PrismaClient {
  constructor (readonly config: ConfigService) {
    super({
      datasources: {
        db: {
          url: config.get('DATABASE_URL')
        }
      }
    })
    this.createAdminUser(this).catch(console.error)
  }

  async createAdminUser (dataService: DataService): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const adminUser: User | null = await dataService.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          email: 'admin@gmail.com'
        }
      })
      if (adminUser != null) {
        const password =
          dataService.config.get('ADMIN_PASSWORD') || 'NotSafePassword1!'
        const hashedPassword = await argon2.hash(password)

        const user = await dataService.user.create({
          data: {
            email: 'admin@gmail.com',
            password: hashedPassword,
            firstName: 'Admin',
            lastName: 'User',
            role: 'ADMIN'
          }
        })

        console.log(`Created admin user with email: ${user.email}`)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is probably in

```
if (adminUser != null)
```

I tried using the conditions

```
if (adminUser !== null && Boolean(adminUser))
```

and

```
if (!!adminUser)
```

but ESlint keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Pretty sure it's caused by the use of short-circuit with `||`... You should be using `??` anyways if your environment supports it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped! I originally used this operator, but I don't know why I refractored it to ||.